# How to generate generate_url and verify_url for Paytm Integration for Android Cordova app?

Tags: android, git, cordova

How can I generate `generate_url` and `verify_url` for Android in the following Cordova command?

```sh
cordova plugin add https://github.com/isathyam/CordovaPayTM.git \
    --variable GENERATE_URL= \
    --variable VERIFY_URL= \
    --variable MERCHANT_ID= \
    --variable INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID= \
    --variable WEBSITE=
```